# In python's ElemenTree library how to use iterparse only for the outer level

Tags: python, memory, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML file with a huge number of records. The structure is like

`<root>
    <record>
        <somedata>here</somedata>
        <complexdata>
            <info>text</info>
            <location>here</location>
        </complexdata>
        .
        .
        .
    </record>
    <record>
        <somedata>not here</somedata>
        <complexdata>
            <info>more text</info>
            <location>there</location>
        </complexdata>
        .
        .
        .
    </record>
    .
    .
    .
</root>`

So the file contains millions of `<record>` structures, however each record structure has only few data and only one or two levels of recursion.

I want is parse the file with python's ElementTree library. To reduce memory footprint I use  `iterparse` to go through all record structures.  On the other hand it would be handy if each record itself would be completely loaded into memory and accessed via normal tree methods.

How can I tell `elementtree` to use for the outer level `iterparse`, but then switch to loading the whole record into an object for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To reduce memory footprint I use iterparse to go through all record
>   structures. On the other hand it would be handy if each record itself
>   would be completely loaded into memory and accessed via normal tree
>   methods.

`iterparse()` returns an `Element`, and an Element is what provides the normal tree methods, e.g. you can search an Element with `findall()`, or you can iterate over an Element, e.g. `for child in elmt:`.  Your `<record>` tags are returned as Element's--you just have to grab them at the right instant:

With this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <record level="0">
        <somedata>here</somedata>
        <complexdata>
            <info>hello</info>
            <location>here</location>
        </complexdata>
        <record level="1"><record level="2">records</record></record>
    </record>
    <record level="0">
        <somedata>not here</somedata>
        <record level="1"></record>
        <complexdata>
            <record level="1"><record level="2"></record></record>
            <info>goodbye</info>
            <location>there</location>
        </complexdata>
    </record>
</root>
```

this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

record_iter = etree.iterparse("xml.xml", ["start", "end"]) 
_, root = next(record_iter)

record_nesting_level = -1 

for (event, elmt) in record_iter:
    if elmt.tag == "record":
        if event == "start": 
            record_nesting_level += 1
        else:  #then it's an "end" event
            if record_nesting_level == 0: #then the elmt should be a top level record tag
                print("{} -- level {}".format(elmt.tag, elmt.attrib["level"])) 
                #Call normal etree methods on elmt:
                for child in elmt:
                    print("\t{}".format(child.tag))

                root.clear()  #empty out the root element so that at most only 
                              #one toplevel record tag will be in memory at a time


            record_nesting_level -= 1
```

produces this result:

```
record -- level 0
    somedata
    complexdata
    record
record -- level 0
    somedata
    record
    complexdata
```

**Response to comment:**

`next()` returns the next item in an iterator. A `for-in` loop such as:

```
for elmt in record_iter:
```

repeatedly calls `next(record_iter)` and assigns the result to the elmt variable.  You can manually call `next()` on an iterator anytime you want.

In the example code, `next(record_iter)` returns the first item in the iterator, which is the tuple:

```
("start", <Element 'root'>)
```

The following:

```
 _, root = next(record_iter)
```

is just a variation of:

```
x, y = (1, 2)

print(x)  #=> 1
print(y)  #=> 2
```

I could have written:

```
x, root = next(record_iter)
```

but because I don't care about the event name, and I won't ever use the `x` variable, I chose a variable named `_` instead.  That's a perfectly legal variable name.  (People who have studied a functional language will often use `_` for a variable they don't care about.)

`elmt.clear()` doesn't delete the `<record>` Element, rather it deletes its contents. If you let `iterparse()` append 100 million empty Element objects to the `<root>` Element, they will use up memory.  How much?  You would have to do some testing--but why bother when it's just as easy to write root.clear()?

Comment: Makes sense. Thx. - But  don't I have with this code the problem that all the elements are still  built up in memory and **not** discarded?

Comment: Thanks for this. The code makes sense, apart from the line `_, root = next(record_iter)` and the subsequent `root.clear()` . Why can't I just reference the current element and say `elmt.clear()`? Seems to work for me...